# Would a minimalist collage still be a collage?

Tags: style, traditional-media, collaboration, minimalistic

There is a collage making competition In my school. I want to make a collage using minimal design principles. Will such a collage even be considered a collage? Because all of the collages I have encountered are extremely unordered with pictures and data seemingly placed at random. The theme is world health day.

Definition of collage:

> a piece of art made by sticking various different materials such as photographs and pieces of paper or fabric on to a backing.

Comment: If it fits the definition, it's by definition a collage...

Comment: Sounds like the assignment's definition doesn't discuss the aesthetic or design of it at all, only the physical construction, so I say go for it.

Comment: Hi Faizan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Nice question, no idea why people are Voting to close this

Comment: I voted to close because this is asking a bunch of random strangers to interpret what the school means. I don't see how anyone here could do that. Someone responsible for the contest should be asked. If the question is "is this a collage" that's just all based on personal opinion, and again, not definitively answerable.

Comment: @Scott I disagree, I think how Faizan creates it would play a role but I can certainly imagine really interesting ways to make a minimalist collage

Comment: @Ryan But that's not *really* the question. The question is "would the school accept it?" That can't be answered here.

Comment: Hi Faizan, I think if you could define what you mean by "minimal design principles", we might be able to help, but it's currently *unclear what you're asking*. I am interested in what you mean, I just can't quite understand what you're asking for in answers.

Comment: Side note: avoid competitions. It's considered spec work and what happens is that the winner chosen is rarely the best design. It's usually a headache more than anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely challenging the norms with your suggestion, but if there is nothing explicit about the design style that goes against the assignment, there should be no reason to avoid it.

You may (or definitely will!) stand out if your collage is very minimal, which is good as long as you're standing out for the right reason. Collages tend to have 0% white space, all of the area is filled, which tends to give them the busy look you mention. If you can conform to the general rules while pushing the boundaries, you may find yourself justly rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a great question!

A part of the definition given on the wikipedia says:

> where the artwork is made from an assemblage of different forms, thus creating a new whole.

That should be a intrinsec part of it. Where you can diferentiate several sources as, oh well... different.

---

We can think that a digital composition where you actually use diferent sources, like a background, a cloudy sky, a subject blend into a new image could fit the definition, but if you can not see the diferent parts, it is not a collage.

But some questions rises, for example, can this image be called a collage?
[image]
(source: http://cdn.visualnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/large.jpg)

I am not sure. It suits the definition. But is it?

---

Here is another example:
http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/g/1665551605954_Sx0fHHqo_g.jpg

(Source: http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/g/1665551605954_Sx0fHHqo_g.jpg)

In my opinion this is a verey minimal collage, but it is a collage.

---

And yet another case.

[image]
(Source: https://payload.cargocollective.com/1/4/142545/1909873/1920s-matt2-vers2_copy.jpg)

Here are clearly diferent elements but what if they are more tightly related, so they are percived as a hole, and not the parts?

Is this picasso a collage?

[image]

---

And another one from NatGeo:
[image]
Source: http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2011/03/age-of-man/interactive/img/1pop.jpg

So, yet another question. Where a collage ends, and starts a mosaic, a texture, a composition?

---

### Randomness and numbers

Probably some degree of randomness should be present, yes. On the old days you could not resize a pice of text or a photo, but the overall work can be controlled.

And yet another question: Is there a minimum number of diferent elements necesary to be called a collage? Probably 3.

In the first image I posted, if we add something else I would clearly calle it a collage.

On the image of the letter "A" It has 2 textures and a shape of a letter. I can se a collage there.

---

**My specific answer would be... If you want to push the definition, push it, but the technique should be clear.**